# Developing reader for onnx models

Tags: julia, protocol-buffers, models

I am trying to make a reader for onnx models in Julia. Generally, onnx models consist of a `model.pb` file, which contains metadata about the model. However, I am not able to figure out how can I use protocol buffers or Julia implementation of protocol buffers (ProtoBuf.jl) to generate data structure from this `model.pb` file, so that I can later generate the Julia code for the model.

Can someone tell me how can I make a reader to load onnx models into Julia?

Comment: question: is this models.pb file actually a protobuf schema file? is there an example?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this in case anyone needs it: Reading ONNX models into the `ModelProto` structure using ProtoBuf.jl is pretty simple:

`using ProtoBuf
f = readproto(open("model.onnx"), Proto.ModelProto())`

And `f` is the corresponding ONNX graph.